# RestKit - Lipo Error: can't open input file in Xcode5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios7, restkit, xcode5

I have an iOS application that i need to upgrade on iOS7. I am using RestKit version 0.10.2. While archiving i get following error.

```
/Applications/Xcode 2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/khawarshahzad/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-fcvmsuowvnqkdseskmuetssnxoww/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyAPP/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyAPP.build/Release-iphoneos/MyAPP.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MyAPP (No such file or directory)
```

Previously i had fixed this error for iOS6 by following instructions on
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/930

But now its not working for iOS7. Here is screenshot for current RestKit.xcodeproj Architectures settings.
[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Huh! finally found the solution. If you are not using any specific feature of arm64 architecture, then just kick it off. 
Go to project -> target (your project name) -> build settings and change architectures to standard architectures (armv7, armv7s), and valid architectures to armv7, armv7s. Set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `Yes`

[image]

Repeat same for `RestKit.xcodeproj`

[image]

Clean your project and Archive.
Best of Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Issue and couldn't fix it, so I just removed the restkit files and all its build settings. after that i used [Cocoapods](http://cocoapods.org/) for restkit and other frameworks. its much better to work with and all these kinda errors are gone. I'm using it since iOS5 and last week I fixed my app for iOS7

Comment: thanks reply. Do you mean if i install RestKit via Cocoapods, are the architecture problems would be fixed? Let me try.

Comment: works for me. tell me if you got any problems after using cocoapods

Comment: Did you use, platform :ios, '5.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~>0.10.3', for Podfile?

Comment: I just use `pod 'RestKit'` and for other frameworks `+version`

Answer (score 0):

If you need this fix for building from the **command line** - and you don't have an *.xcodeproj then this will fix it:

Change:

```
(cd $BUILDDIR/i386;  "$SIM_DEV_DIR/ar" crus some.a obj/*.o; )
```

To:

```
# have to take ar from ARM_DEV_DIR in xcode 5
(cd $BUILDDIR/i386;  "$ARM_DEV_DIR/ar" crus some.a obj/*.o; )
```

IOW: In xCode5 `ar` has moved from $SIM_DEV_DIR/ar to $ARM_DEV_DIR/ar